# How to get the "committer" info that Git will use

Tags: git

Reading the doc, I see that I could predict what Git will use as "committer" by combining `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` along with `$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`.  But when I write the code which does that, I end up with the feeling that I'm rewriting a chunk of code that's already in Git and I'd much rather reuse Git's own code for that.

So, just like I prefer to use `git rev-parse --git-dir` rather than to look for a `.git` and/or check for `$GIT_DIR`, I'd like to use a command like `git show-me-the --committer` to get the usual `NAME <EMAIL>` string.  Yet I haven't been able to find this in the manual(s).

Comment: Hackish, but you could make a commit and dump the info from it

Comment: You could even create that commit using `git commit-tree` to avoid updating any refs: `git show -s --format='%cn <%ce>' $(git commit-tree $(git write-tree) </dev/null)`. But yeah, there should be a cleaner way than that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `git var` command:

```
git var GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT
```

This can be run outside of any Git worktree, prints the committer info in the format `name <email> timestamp timezone`, and uses the same Git code that also gets run when committing, so respects the configuration keys and environment variables. Depending on what you want to do with this info, you may need to filter out the timestamp and timezone.

Comment: Good find. I was working on assembling a string in bash and inserting the output of `git config` commands, but this is much simpler.

Comment: This filters out the extra info: `git var GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT | sed 's/>.*/>/'` , but credit to @hvd for the original answer.

Comment: Or `git var GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT | awk '{ NF-=2; print }'`, or `committer=$(git var GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT); committer=${committer%\>*}\>`, or any of the many other ways. :)